# How to open notepad using C in codeblocks?

Tags: c, codeblocks

[image: This is what happening 0 error, 0 warnings but still not opening notepad]

**I used this code but was unable to open notepad using codeblocks**
Is there any specific setting for codeblocks to run this program?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<windows.h>
void main()
{
 system("notepad.exe");
 getch();
}
```

Comment: What does "unable to open notepad " mean?

Comment: from what I see it should work, try providing the full path "c:\\windows\\nodepad.exe"

Comment: @OldProgrammer it mean not able to open notepad here

Comment: @phoenixstudio tried that still was not able to open notepad

Comment: worst case scenario , use this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa, but before that , see if you can open notepad in command line, (just typing notepad) to be sure if the problem is coming from your code or from your OS

Comment: Do you get an error, or notepad never starts?

Comment: @OldProgrammer 0 error and 2 warnings

Comment: @phoenixstudio yes I was able to open notepad from command prompt

Comment: "Warnings" usually come from the compiler. Are you actually running the program?

Comment: @HuHu , I tested your program it work fine, build your code and run it from somewhere else (a CMD where you can launch Notepad.exe without problems)

Comment: @phoenixstudio isn't there a way to do it in code blocks ?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial - https://www.technobyte.org/install-code-blocks-gcc-compiler-first-c-program-windows-10/

Comment: @OldProgrammer I am running windows 8 currently, is that problem coming because of my windows version?

Comment: Please describe in detail what happens when you build and when you run the program.

Comment: @Yunnosch i provided the screenshot link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: It seems unlikely that the shown code compiles into an exe with that behaviour. Please insert a printf before and after trying to open the editor, build again, check the file date of the exe you are executing (should be a few seconds old), run and verify that the printfs become visible.

Comment: If that does not yield helpful info, please insert a line `#error This actually does get compiled. Good.` into the code and then compile again. I somehow doubt, that the code you look at makes the program you execute. This experiment can verify that.

Comment: If you edit your question, please check the preview of the appearance and make sure that what you edit results in a readable post, without e.g. parts being represented as code. Links e.g. do not work, if the system considers them code quotes...

Comment: Error `';' before system()`... you have a weird char around no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code provided is successfully running on windows 10 as codeblocks recent version is mainly designed for windows 10, it did open notepad on windows 10, THANK YOU.